# How to map DTO from EF to Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, interface, model, separation-of-concerns

I have the following model Person in my UI MVC layer:

```
public class Person
{
     [Required]
     public string FirstName { get; set; }

     [Required]
     public string LastName { get; set; }

     public int PersonTypeID { get; set; }

     [Required]
     public string Phone { get; set; }

     [Required]
     public string Email { get; set; }

}
```

In my data layer, I have a class with the same property names, but different meta (naturally):

```
public partial class Person : EntityObject { ... }
```

How can I return data from my data layer into my MVC UI layer without having the data layer know about the MVC UI layer?

Note:  I also have a simple IPerson interface with the same property names as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to map between the domain model and the view model. It is the MVC layer that knows about the data layer, but the data layer doesn't need to know about the MVC layer.

Here's a common pattern:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    var person = _repository.GetPerson();
    var personViewModel = Mapper.Map<Person, PersonViewModel>(person);
    return View(personViewModel);
}
```

and the other way around:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(PersonViewModel personViewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
    var person = Mapper.Map<PersonViewModel, Person>(personViewModel);
    _repository.UpdatePerson(person);
    return RedirectToAction("Success");
}
```

As you can see the data layer doesn't need to know anything about the MVC layer. It's the MVC layer that needs to know about the data layer.

Comment: The only issue I see with this is if you ever need to switch your data implementation (from EF to Linq to SQL, for example).  Now your MVC layer wants the Person object, which is an tied to EF exclusively.

Comment: @BrianDavidBerman, well, there's no miracle solution. The best would be to have an ORM framework which is not intrusive and allows you to map your actual domain objects so that you don't get some autogenerated and polluted classes. As far as I know this is possible with EF. The best solution is to have pure domain business entities which are not specific to some data access framework but are specific to the business requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I would invite you to review a framework such [automapper](http://automapper.org/) which gives you the ability to easily perform object to object mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Other option is [CX.Mapper](https://github.com/CXRom/CX.Mapper) very simple to use and you dont need to precofig the Map:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
  var item = this.db.Items.Find(id);
  var model = CX.Mapper.Mapping.MapNew<Item, ItemDto>(item);
  return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ItemDto model)
{
  if(Model.IsValid)
  {
    var item = this.db.Items.Find(ItemDto.Id);
    CX.Mapper.Mapping.Map<ItemDto, Item>(model, item);
    this.db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
  return View(model);
}
```

You can install with NuGet